# App Engine Standard Laravel 5.8 Escritura de sesion

Tags: laravel-5, google-app-engine

Estoy intentando desplegar laravel en un App Engine Standard.
Mi app.yaml es este:

```
runtime: php72
env_variables:
  APP_DEBUG: 'True'
  APP_ENV: production
  APP_KEY: 'MiKey'
  APP_NAME: MiApp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
```

Tengo el .gcloudignore así:

```
.gcloudignore
/vendor/
/.idea/
composer.lock
```

El laravel es un laravel recién instalado `laravel new MiApp`

Luego hice un `composer install` y todo bien.

En el bootstrap/app.php ya añadí `$app->useStoragePath(env('APP_STORAGE', base_path() . '/storage'));`

Pero cuando hago un `gcloud beta app deploy` y accedo a la versión recién subida me aparece un error a la hora de escribir la sesión de laravel en disco:

```
file_put_contents(/tmp/framework/sessions/xs4QqPK5yzCcK5vokXDtEABCZbcaMorxGX0BcNzG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Y no tengo claro porqué me está pasando, he probado mil despliegues con mil opciones tocadas... el php.ini y demás...

¿Alguno sabe como instalar un laravel en un app engine standard? En el entorno flexible me va correctamente.

Gracias

Comment: Yo tuve el mismo problema y cambie el session storage a DB y se soluciono. Si te sirve, es una opción. Saludos!

Comment: Sí, al final lo conseguí... poniendo todo (sesiones, carpeta bootstrap, cache) a /tmp. Hay que modificar "cosas" del kernel pero llega a funcionar... pero la web me va muuucho más lenta en standard que en flex...